# Is there a way to make Google App Engine print out any and all Python errors whenever it encounters them? I'm getting server errors, but no idea why

Tags: python, google-app-engine

*So* many times I have seen this screen:

```
Server error  
The website encountered an error while retrieving http://localhost:8080/. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.
Here are some suggestions:
Reload this webpage later.  
HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error):  
An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.
```

Obviously, that gives absolutely no useful information. So I have to systematically undo everything I've previously coded, with each step reloading the page to see if I've found what ever it is that app engine doesn't like, and the whole process is just... demoralizing.

I just spent a half-hour digging through my code trying to figure out what was broken. Turned out GAE didn't like a module I was importing -- note that I still have *no* idea why it doesn't like it, but that's beside the point.

My question is this, is there a way to have report any and all errors? I have Debug set to true, but it very finicky about when it will actually print out the stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever framework you're using is generating that.  There's probably an exception handler that will generate your 500 message.  You'll have to find that and adjust it to not catch all exceptions.

Can't help you figure out where though, I'm not sure what framework you're using.

Answer (score 0):

By default - for most frameworks - exceptions are logged rather than output to the user, since there's no point in showing your user a stacktrace of your app's internal details. If you're running the dev_appserver, these show up in the console window; in production these can be accessed via the log viewer.